# Create a table + populate it using another table in One Query

Tags: sql

I'm using Access 2000 and I have 2 queries:

The first one is:

```
CREATE TABLE first_table_name (....)
```

The second is:

```
INSERT INTO first_table_name [(column1, column2, ... columnN)] 
   SELECT column1, column2, ...columnN 
   FROM second_table_name
   [WHERE condition];
```

Is it possible to do the same thing (create a table and immediately fill it using another table) with just one query?

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: In Sql server `insert into table1 value (select * from table2)` , condition both should have same structure

Comment: Sorry, forgot to precise i'm using Microsoft Access 2000 ! But already received working answers, thank you everyone !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...columnN 
   into first_table_name 
   FROM second_table_name
   [WHERE condition];
```

first_table_name will have same table column as second table name

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...columnN 
INTO new_table
FROM second_table_name
[WHERE condition];
```

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:  **INSERT INTO SELECT**

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM Table2
```

Method 2:  **SELECT INTO**

```
SELECT col1, col2
INTO Table1 
FROM Table2
```

Note: Table contain same schema

Answer (score 0):

inserting into one table records selected from another one is possible, here is the doc. in case you are using mysql : [mysql insert select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/insert-select.html?ff=nopfpls)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM second_table_name WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is :

`SELECT blah INTO [ #local | ##global ] FROM ... WHERE`

But this is not a permanent table and will disappear when ...

if #local table then when user disconnects
 if ##global table then when all users using it disconnect

So not a great solution.

You can write a stored procedure to do the create + insert and then execute it in lots of places with just one subsequent statement, but that's kind of cheating with the answer.